# Am I using mocks and stubs here correctly? mocha/minitest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm working with stubs and mocks trying to figure the correct way to test a method that returns a 6 digit random number.

Specifically I want the test to confirm that `Foo.generate_number` returns a number between `000000` and `999999`.

Below are my test setup and the method I am trying to test.  Am I doing this test correctly?

Test:

```
require "minitest/autorun"
require 'mocha/minitest'

class FooTest < Minitest::Test
  def test_it_can_return_random_number
    Foo.expects(:generate_number).returns(rand(99999).to_s.rjust(5,'0'))
    assert Foo.generate_number
  end
end
```

Class:

```
class Foo
  def self.generate_number
    rand(99999).to_s.rjust(5,'0')
  end
end
```

Am I doing this right?

Answer (score 2):

Couldn't you assert that generate_number is between 0 and 999999 instead of stubbing?

The way I see it, your "generate_number" function is doing **two things**: **generating a random number** AND also **formatting it**. If you separate those behaviours into two methods - generate_number and format_number - testing becomes trivial.

```
    random_number = Foo.generate_number

    assert random_number >= 0
    assert random_number < 99999

    formatted_number = Foo.format_number random_number
    assert formatted_number.size == 5
```

Disclaimer: not an expert on MiniTest, there are probably clearer assertions than the above.

Comment: Gotcha, that makes sense.  We've been challenged in a course I am taking to use mocks/stubs for testing random returns from methods.  So I have to go that route unfortunately, thanks for the feedback though.